# Can I use the ID of a control as parameter to subroutine in ASP using VB?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a page that has many (100+) fields that are all similar in their function. When the page is displayed, a value read from a database for each field will be checked to determine the display properties of the field and a couple of related fields. see code example.

```
                If fieldvalue = 2 Then
                    Myfield.visible = False
                    Myfieldx.Checked = False
                    Myfieldz.visible = True
                ElseIf fieldvalue = 1 Then
                    Myfield.visible = True
                    Myfieldx.Checked = True
                    Myfieldz.visible = False
                Else
                    Myfield.visible = True
                    Myfieldx.Checked = False
                    Myfieldz.visible = False
                End If
```

Each field has identical testing done. Each group of fields also has a fixed naming convention so that I can potentially use a subroutine to do this. 
Fieldname, fieldname+x, fieldname+z

The code above works great but it is a lot of code to replicate for that many fields (each with a different ID). I would like to simplify the above code use a routine to do this testing. Something like

```
Protected Sub CheckStatusLoad(ByVal fieldID As String, ByVal fieldvalue As Integer)
    Dim fieldIDx As String, fieldIDz As String

    fieldIDx = String.Concat(fieldID, "x")
    fieldIDz = String.Concat(fieldID, "z")

    Dim Mainfield As New WebControls.Button
    Dim MainfieldChkBox As New WebControls.CheckBox
    Dim MainfieldStrike As New WebControls.Button

    Mainfield = DirectCast(Page.FindControl(fieldID), WebControls.Button)
    MainfieldChkBox = DirectCast(Page.FindControl(fieldIDx), WebControls.CheckBox)
    MainfieldStrike = DirectCast(Page.FindControl(fieldIDz), WebControls.Button)

    If fieldvalue = 2 Then
        Mainfield.Visible = False
        MainfieldChkBox.Checked = False
        MainfieldStrike.Visible = True
    ElseIf fieldvalue = 1 Then
        Mainfield.Visible = True
        MainfieldChkBox.Checked = True
        MainfieldStrike.Visible = False
    Else
        Mainfield.Visible = True
        MainfieldChkBox.Checked = False
        MainfieldStrike.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Then call this for each field being loaded

```
CheckStatusLoad("fieldname", testval)
```

This code now works using FindControl. I just needed to play around with the syntax to get the quotes adjusted properly.

Comment: Look into [`Page.FindControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31hxzsdw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I looked but I'm not sure I follow that. It looked like it was related to an array which mine is not.  In my code "Myfield" is independent from that next control which could be "Yourfield" but has an associated Yourfieldx and Yourfieldz.

Comment: OK. I looked more into Page.FindControl and this code works in a Protected Sub for the html ID of fieldIDx:
    Dim MainfieldChkBox As New WebControls.CheckBox
    Mainfield = DirectCast(Page.FindControl("fieldIDx"), WebControls.Button)
    MainfieldChkBox = DirectCast(Page.FindControl("fieldIDx"), WebControls.CheckBox)

What I want to be able to do is make "fieldIDx" be a parameter that is passed to the Sub

Comment: Thanks freefaller. After looking at some other examples the FindControl made more sense.

Answer (score 0):

The code above has been edited so that it now works. It took me a while to understand Page.FindControl, but once I got the proper syntax it worked just fine.